# My equation's referencing not working

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I can't reference my equations, I've labeled all my equations, and am referencing them with \ref{}, but only two question marks appear. I've tried everything and can't for the life of me understand why it doesn't work. I have been able to reference figures, but not equations. An excerpt of the code is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

...
\begin{equation}\label{eq:funcao_dif}
v_1 = K v_i + \frac{v_2}{Q} - v_3 = K v_i - \frac{1}{sT}\frac{1}{Q} v_1  + 
\frac{1}{sT} v_2 = K v_i - \frac{1}{sT}\frac{1}{Q} v_1  - \frac{1}{s^2T^2} 
v_1 
\end{equation}
...

{\par A primeira parte é logo um circuito subtractor que simula a equação 
\ref{eq:funcao_dif}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please remove any unnecessary package and make your document fragment compilable (MWE).

Comment: unrelated to `\label`, but why do you have `\par` and a `{...}` group around your paragraph?

Comment: do not use `etex` package  with current latex, don't load  `blindtext` or `lipsum`  in real documents, most likely you should use `[utf8]` rather than `[utf8x]` unless you really need some of the non standard features of the utf8x version.

Answer (score 5):

You are loading a lot of un-needed packages in your preamble and experiencing a clash of redefinitions. In particular the `cleverref` manual explains that it must be loaded last (and in particular, after `hyperref`).

This version works

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{cleveref}
%\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

...
\begin{equation}\label{eq:funcao_dif}
v_1 = K v_i + \frac{v_2}{Q} - v_3 = K v_i - \frac{1}{sT}\frac{1}{Q} v_1  + 
\frac{1}{sT} v_2 = K v_i - \frac{1}{sT}\frac{1}{Q} v_1  - \frac{1}{s^2T^2} 
v_1 
\end{equation}
...

{\par A primeira parte é logo um circuito subtractor que simula a equação 
\ref{eq:funcao_dif}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I had this in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[nosumlimits,nointlimits,nonamelimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage[round,authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.6,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.5}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkgreen]{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
```

It turns out that I had to move `ntheorem` before `amsmath`. There is probably some conflict between these two packages, and `ntheorem` must come first.

Comment: I also had this problem, and while your solution works, the `ntheorem` documentation suggests otherwise. According to section 3.2.1, when using the `thmmarks` option with `ntheorem`, if also using `amsmath`, `amsmath` should be loaded first and `ntheorem` should be included as `\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}`.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You should use the package `\usepackage{hyperref}` to try with `\eqref{eq:funcao_dif}` or `\ref{eq:funcao_dif}`. I think this will work.

Output of following shown in image.

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:funcao_dif}
v_1 = K v_i + \frac{v_2}{Q} - v_3 = K v_i - \frac{1}{sT}\frac{1}{Q} v_1  + 
\frac{1}{sT} v_2 = K v_i - \frac{1}{sT}\frac{1}{Q} v_1  - \frac{1}{s^2T^2} 
v_1 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You should to try with `\eqref{eq:funcao_dif}` or  `\ref{eq:funcao_dif}`.  I think this will work.

Comment: I am sorry but this answer is wrong, you do not need `hyperref` to use `\ref` and `\label`.

Comment: Please try following:- with and without {hyperref} it will be clear.

Comment: @alphy `hyperref` adds hyperlinks but `\label` and `\ref` work fine without the package

Comment: Sir, I've tried both with and without {hyperref}. Its working when using \usepackage{hyperref}.